# How to remove strange character in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

After clicking on "some" hot keys I saw this problem. Please see the attached screenshot.
Now, I can't find this hotkey.

[image]

Does anyone know how to clean this up?

Comment: This looks like a Unicode Upwards Harpoon character. It's not clear why it's displayed there. Are you sure it's not in he code? Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the sample project to reproduce the issue and the IDE logs: Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: it has happened today.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ErcYzdn20gTCX6AZeOVvSGs6iZBO0548/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does it help if you change the editor font?